# How to use JSLint with the code aimed to different engines?

Tags: javascript, jslint

Consider, for example, the following Node.js code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    /*jslint node: true */

    var toBeExecutedInBrowser = function () {
        "use strict";
        /*jslint devel: true */
        alert('Hello world!');
    };

    exports.controller = function (req, res) {
        res.send(toBeExecutedInBrowser.toString());
    };
}());
```

The latest JSLint version [unconditionally fails](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L2386) checking this code. Apparently, JSLint author does not want to answer what are we supposed to do in this case, judging by him deleting my questions; but maybe someone out there could answer what should I do in such a case?

- I do not want to significantly change the application logic;
- I do not want to write unsafe code by letting the client-side mode to be executed in a non-strict context (something Douglas Crockford supposedly also wants);
- I do not want to write unsafe code by disabling JSLint for this file entirely (something Douglas Crockford supposedly also wants);
- I do not want the JSLint report to be "spammed" by the `unnecessary 'use strict'` messages, so that it will be possible to overlook something really important.

Comment: By the way, if someone is interested, there is a [patch](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/pull/131) to JSLint allowing one to suppress specific messages entirely. It compensates for JSLint lacking options to disable specific checks (such as nested `"use strict";` check in question).

Answer (score 2):

You may find **[JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/)** interesting. It's a more merciful version of JSLint. Also, it has a NodeJS option.

Comment: JSHint is *too much* merciful for my taste, it skips many mistakes JSLint catches.

Comment: +1 *globalstrict: This option suppresses warnings about the use of global strict mode.* Much more configurable than JSLint, and therefore more usable/powerful.

Comment: @penartur: How do you define "mistakes"? What is it unable to catch that you feel it should?

Comment: @amnotiam I'm not using JSHint directly; I'm rather checking my code with [autolint](https://github.com/magnars/autolint), so I was unaware JSLint prohibits one from writing global `"use strict";`, which may have caused you to misunderstood my question. Please, check out the updated question.

Comment: @amnotiam Unfortunately, I do not have access to the code now as it is a holiday; but there definitely were some code problems that JSLint caught while JSHint (even with all the options set to be as strict as possible) skipped.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer This option is only [defining some global variables](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L850) and [allows one to use non-functional form of `"use strict";`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/master/jslint.js#L2933) (which is, curiously, something [Douglas Crockford objected to](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/issues/124).